# SimpleAudioEngine shuffle playlist

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

i want to shuffle a dozen of songs in my game. Next song should not be the same as current song.

```
[[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic: song];
```

There should be a loop and song should be randomized,

```
[[NSString stringWithFormat: @"song%i.mp3", arc4random() % 20 + 1];
//20 songs starting from song1.mp3
```

It would be great if the song will stop playing when the user's ipod music is playing. But the sound effect should still be available:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect: @"aaa.caf"]
```

Also, when the ipod music is playing, then launch the game, game music should not even be started.

How to implement this?

Comment: the playlist is from my game, not users' ipod playlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start your app, you can check like this and play or not your own music.

```
if ([[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
    // dont play and do whatever you think should be done in this case
} else {
    [[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic: song];
}
```

Side note:

```
//Remember to preload your effects and bg music so there is not any delay
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"aaa.caf"];
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadBackgroundMusic:@"song1.mp3"];
//And to unload your effects when you wont use them anymore or receive a mem warning, or in dealloc
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] unloadEffect:@"aaa.caf"];
```

**UPDATE**

In viewDidLoad, create an strings array with all your songs and shuffle them with: [self shuffle],for this implement this code:

```
- (void)shuffle {
    for (NSInteger i = [songsArray count] - 1; i > 0; --i) [songsArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:(arc4random() % (i+1)) withObjectAtIndex:i];
}
```

Every time your background music finishes use `[self shuffle]` and then `playBackgroundMusic:[songsArray lastObject]` that should take care of your shuffled playlist.

Comment: what i need is to shuffle a playlist. randomly choose a new song to play after finishing current song. your code will play only one song

Comment: how can i trigger -(void) shuffle when one song is done playing.

Comment: Im not familiar with _SimpleAudioEngine_ you could check if there is any kind of notification you could use.

Comment: There is a method called didFinishedPlaying for NSSound, but as i said, i dont know about _SimpleAudioEngine_

Comment: I just add a if-else in the shuffle, if music is not playing, then pick one song to play. then schedule your shuffle method. it works well now.